# How can I parse this variable?

Tags: command-line, bash, midi

I have a midi keyboard I want to read the output of and parse to execute various commands.
I have run `amidi -p "hw:1,0,0" -d`
which returns a list of keys pressed hex values, as various keys are pressed.
such as:

```
E00010 
904E63
E00018
804E00
E0001C
904E63
E00014
E00010
804E00
E0000C
904E63
804E00
```

The input variable:
`input=$(amidi -p "hw:1,0,0" -d)`
was never getting a value, because its streaming data. So I made it   `input=$(amidi -p "$MIDI_DEVICE" -d | head -n "$NUM")`. If I set NUM to 1, I never get a return value, just loads of newlines. The key presses are in sets of 3, that are basically a hex value for the set of keys having been pressed: (E000XX), the note being pressed: (904E63 for example), and the release return value (804E00).

If I set NUM=2, all I seem to get is section values, no notes.
setting NUM >=3, I will get the notes, but the order gets skewed, which means I cant `cut` based on the number of lines or columns.

I am looking for advice on how to parse the (note) values in the `$input` variable.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
#MIDI_DEVICE="hw:1,0,0"  # Adjust with your MIDI device ID
NUM=4
while true; do
   #input=$(amidi -p $MIDI_DEVICE -d) 
   input=$(amidi -p "hw:1,0,0" -d | head -n $NUM) 
  note=$(echo $input | cut -d' ' -f2 | cut -c 2-3)
  
echo $input
  case "$note" in
      "904E63")  #trigger note
          xdotool key ctrl+alt+t  # Open a terminal
          ;;
        # Add more cases for different MIDI notes and corresponding actions
  esac
done
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not something I can test, however I wonder if `amidi` buffers when its output is piped? Regardless, I'd try something more like `while read x && read y && read z; do printf '%s %s %s\n' "$x" "$y" "$z"; done < <(amidi -p "hw:1,0,0" -d)` (replace the `printf` by whatever you want to do with the values)

Comment: Regarding the key press event order is skewed: how about doing a read line loop, and filter out unwanted data, and process the rest. e.g. ignore "804E00" lines and lines that starts with "E". i.e. `while read e; do if [[ "$e" != 804E00 && "$e" != E* ]]; then echo $e; fi; done < <(amidi -p "hw:1,0,0" -d)`

Comment: yeah, @aff, that does make sense. I was tripping on getting the output, but I can just read it line by line.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to parse the output of `amidi` is to replace is with a tool that outputs properly-separated values:

```
#!/bin/bash
aseqdump -p "My Device" | \
while IFS=" ," read src ev1 ev2 ch label1 data1 label2 data2 rest; do
    case "$ev1 $ev2 $data1" in
        "Note on 64" ) xdotool type hello ;;
        "Note on 48" ) xdotool key ctrl+j ;;
    esac
done
```

<sup>(source: my [original answer](https://superuser.com/a/1170232))</sup>